# Stuck at page 52 of Web Application Development with Yii 2 and PHP

Tags: php, composer-php, yii2

Hi got to page 52 and I am getting an exception trying to view the customers/add route.

I managed to fix it by creating a soft link - but why should I need to and is this the correct way to fix it or has the book become out-of-sync with the yii code-base

I checked the errata and applied the fix suggested (and also what is in the example download book code)

I know books go out of date - but this is the error I am getting

```
PHP User Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Exception 'yii\base\InvalidParamException' with message 'The file or directory to be published does not exist: /var/www/html/crmapp/vendor/bower/jquery/dist' 

in /var/www/html/crmapp/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php:385
...
```

Now the bower directory is not on my machine even though I followed all the composer instructions to install stuff so far I have

```
[adrian@eagle:/var/www/html/crmapp]$ ls vendor/bower-asset/jquery/dist/
jquery.js  jquery.min.js  jquery.min.map
[adrian@eagle:/var/www/html/crmapp]$
```

Ok I managed to fix it by creating a soft-link

```
[adrian@eagle:/var/www/html/crmapp]$ ls -l vendor/
total 64
-rw-rw-r-- 1 adrian adrian  183 Jan  6 21:19 autoload.php
drwxrwxr-x 2 adrian adrian 4096 Jan  6 21:19 bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 adrian adrian   12 Jan 12 19:28 bower -> bower-asset/
drwxrwxr-x 6 adrian adrian 4096 Jan  6 21:19 bower-asset
drwxrwxr-x 3 adrian adrian 4096 Jan  6 21:19 cebe
```

Book:
https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/web-application-development-yii-2-and-php

Comment: Don't you need to do a `bower install` or something?

Comment: Problem is probably almost nobody has this book in front of them and has no context for what's in the book.

Comment: @deceze Agree - but also cut&pasting 52 pages of instructions from a book is also not cool. I want to know if the book is incorrect or I missed something

Comment: Yup, also not cool. The best course of action really is to make your question self contained without any reference to the book. :)

Comment: @deceze Hard to do when the book said do X and X didn't work -:(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This folder should have name `bower` and not `bower-asset`. Renaming is managed automatically.

Did you follow [installation instructions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#installing-via-composer)?

I think the problem is that you did not execute this command before installing / updating composer packages:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.3"
```

It should be run only once, then run `composer update` again.

You can find more information about this plugin on [official Github page](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin/).

**Update:**

After more detailed investigation I found out that he is trying to build application from scratch without templates.

`composer.json` was not up-to-date to framework last changes. These settings were missing:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
}
```

As **Adrian** said these details were not mentioned in this book section.

Up-to-date `composer.json` files are available here for each template:

- [Basic](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/composer.json)
- [Advanced](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/composer.json)

Comment: Ah the book has no mention of `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0-beta4"` - I did not follow the yii instructions this time as I was following the book

Comment: Everything changes fast, the books can't cover all of these details. Even if you are learning from the book, you should look at the documentation too. Also this plugin was added close to release, so propably at the moment of the book released the installation of this plugin was not required.

Comment: What's the current structure of 'vendor' folder? Does it have 'bower' folder? Or 'bower-asset'? Or both of them?

Comment: Agree and I know - was just checking it was not my stupity

Comment: To make it work I created a softlink
`[adrian@eagle:/var/www/html/crmapp/vendor]$ ls -l
total 64
-rw-rw-r-- 1 adrian adrian  183 Jan 12 21:39 autoload.php
drwxrwxr-x 2 adrian adrian 4096 Jan 12 21:38 bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 adrian adrian   12 Jan 12 21:44 bower -> bower-asset/
drwxrwxr-x 6 adrian adrian 4096 Jan 12 21:38 bower-asset`

Comment: Remove that link and try to update again, creation of this folder managed automatically during installation.

Comment: `[adrian@eagle:/var/www/html/crmapp]$ ls -ld vendor/bow*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 adrian adrian   12 Jan 12 21:51 vendor/bower -> bower-asset/
drwxrwxr-x 6 adrian adrian 4096 Jan 12 21:38 vendor/bower-asset
[adrian@eagle:/var/www/html/crmapp]$ rm vendor/bower
[adrian@eagle:/var/www/html/crmapp]$ php composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
[adrian@eagle:/var/www/html/crmapp]$ ls -ld vendor/bow*
drwxrwxr-x 6 adrian adrian 4096 Jan 12 21:38 vendor/bower-asset
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68701/discussion-between-arogachev-and-adrian).

Comment: thanks for the help when you update - I'll accept this as the answer - thanks for your time helping me